# Place div at specific coordinates using something like the coords attribute of a map area

Tags: html, css, dictionary, area

Is there a way I could place a div on top of a certain spot in an image? Say I have the coordinates of that spot that would be used in an HTML map area, what would I need to do to reuse those coordinates for placing that div?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see, [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try looking up _overlay image_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could wrap your image in a div, and set that div's position to `relative` then you can place inner div to `absolute`

```
<div class="relative">
<img your map/>
<div class="pin"><img your pin image></div>
</div>

.relative{
position:relative
}
.pin{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:50px;
}
```

Of course you would set top and left via javascript as needed

Comment: That definitely got my pin to appear on the image, yay! Now, is there any way I can reuse the area coordinates when determining the top/left positions? Say i have a rect area with coordinates 182,240,241,263. If I were to use those for to determine my top and left properties, it ends up in a different location. Sorry if that's a dumb question

Answer (score 0):

You can also absolutely position the parent div on the page and add a background image to the parent. Then relatively position the child div within the parent div, like this: https://embed.plnkr.co/gM2VNz/

Answer (score 0):

You should do some easy math. For example your image is showing 100,100 in top left and 400,400 in right bottom of the image and the image is 300x300.
 And you would like to pin 130,130 coordination
You would do this
400-100 is your box
130-100=30/300*100 = 10
So 10% from left and top is your pin position